# iOS - Is it possible to make a phone call programmatically blocking any kind of outgoing phone call sound?

Tags: ios, callkit

I'm trying to make an iOS app that can programmatically make a phone call silently, blocking any kind of outgoing phone call sound. (After the phone call is ready the app would then start recording the audio from the microphone.) Does anyone know if that's possible or have any idea about how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Apple is really protective in such core features as calls. So we as a programmers have really narrow API to use. Basically, to make a call you have two options:

1. Open URL with format like `tel://`
2. Init call with instance of `CXStartCallAction`

Everything happens after is held by the system, so you don't have much of control over it. To be concrete, you have no control over call sounds.

You can have much more control, if you use VoIP or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome Antonio!
Briefly, no you can not.**

Let me explain further...

> After the recipient answers the call, the system calls the provider
>   delegate’s provider(_:perform:) method. In your implementation of that
>   method, configure an AVAudioSession and call the fulfill() method on
>   the action object when finished.

You may have some doing to configure audio session but the system would block the microphone and from the API side you will not have access whatsoever.

I am deeply sorry for being so blunt, but what you're intending is simply no possible.